How do I repair "mailcap" in Ubuntu Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I get the following error:
"Error: '/etc/mailcap' is not in required format -- not updated
Restore from backup or delete and
re-install mime-support packageProcessing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ..."
How do I delete it and re-install it. BTW - I do not have a backup to use.
